# SQL CTE: Avoiding Duplicate Results

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have two CTEs which are of the below form:

```
WITH Migrated12ncs_CTE ( EcnID, EcnReleaseDate, SolutionItemId, 
    SolutionItemRevisionId )
TcBomBopOwned12ncRevs_CTE ( ItemID, ItemRevisionID, ItemRevisionDateReleased )
```

On the content of my database, if I run this SQL query, I get the following results:

[image]

This is the complete SQL:

```
-- All the 12nc revisions that are sent to SAP via an ECN, either Migration ECN or a regular ECN.
WITH Migrated12ncs_CTE ( EcnID, EcnReleaseDate, SolutionItemId, SolutionItemRevisionId )
AS (
  select ecnItem.pitem_id as ECN_Item, wsoECNRev.PDATE_RELEASED as ECNReleasedDate, solutionItem.pitem_id as Solution_Item, solutionItemRevision.pItem_Revision_Id
  from infodba.pItemRevision solutionItemRevision
  inner join infodba.pImanRelation solutionItemsRelation ON solutionItemRevision.puid = solutionItemsRelation.RSECONDARY_OBJECTU
  inner join infodba.pItemRevision ecnRevision ON  ecnRevision.puid = solutionitemsrelation.Rprimary_Objectu
  inner join infodba.pItem solutionItem on solutionItem.puid = solutionItemRevision.rItems_Tagu
  inner join infodba.pItem ecnItem on ecnItem.puid = ecnRevision.rItems_Tagu
  inner join infodba.pWorkspaceObject wsoECN ON wsoECN.puid = ecnItem.puid
  inner join infodba.pWorkspaceObject wsoECNRev ON wsoECNRev.puid = ecnRevision.puid
  inner join infodba.pImanType solutionItemsRelationType on solutionItemsRelationType.puid = solutionItemsRelation.RRELATION_TYPEU
  where wsoECN.pobject_type LIKE 'A5ml_ECN'
  and solutionItemsRelationType.PTYPE_NAME LIKE 'CMHasSolutionItem'
  -- DEBUG and wsoECN.pobject_name LIKE 'Migration ECN'
  order by ecnItem.pitem_id ASC, solutionItem.pitem_id ASC ),

-- All the 12ncs revisions that are now in the Teamcenter database that are owned by TcBomBop
TcBomBopOwned12ncRevs_CTE ( ItemID, ItemRevisionID, ItemRevisionDateReleased )
AS (
  select item.pItem_Id, itemRevision.pItem_Revision_Id, wsoItemRevision.PDATE_RELEASED
  from infodba.pItem item
  inner join infodba.pItemRevision itemRevision ON  item.puid = itemRevision.rItems_Tagu
  inner join infodba.pPOM_Application_Object paoItemRevision ON itemRevision.puid = paoItemRevision.puid
  inner join infodba.pWorkspaceObject wsoItemRevision ON paoItemRevision.puid = wsoItemRevision.puid
  inner join infodba.pPOM_User pomUser ON pomUser.puid = paoItemRevision.ROWNING_USERU
  where pomUser.puser_id LIKE 'tcbombop' )

-- Get all those 12nc revisions that are in the database which are owned by TcBomBop, where an earlier revision under the 12nc Item was either migrated
-- via a Migration ECN or sent to SAP via a normal ECN.
select *
from TcBomBopOwned12ncRevs_CTE
inner join Migrated12ncs_CTE on Migrated12ncs_CTE.SolutionItemId = TcBomBopOwned12ncRevs_CTE.ItemID
where ItemRevisionDateReleased > EcnReleaseDate
and ItemRevisionID > SolutionItemRevisionId
and TcBomBopOwned12ncRevs_CTE.ItemID LIKE 'TOOL.656.34901';
```

What can I do to ensure that I only end up with a unique ItemID, ItemRevisionID when I query the join of the two CTEs - currently as you can see, I get two rows with the same content ( note that I am interested in selecting only two of the columns ).

I really would like to improve my SQL proficiency.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Edit 1: Adding the complete result of the result set as requested.

```
4022.658.59991  AE  20-AUG-18   ECN-600114  01-JUN-18   4022.658.59991  AC
4022.658.60001  AE  20-AUG-18   ECN-600114  01-JUN-18   4022.658.60001  AC
4022.658.59951  AD  20-AUG-18   ECN-600117  01-JUN-18   4022.658.59951  AB
TOOL.656.22331  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600133  01-JUN-18   TOOL.656.22331  AA
TOOL.656.30131  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600141  01-JUN-18   TOOL.656.30131  AA
TOOL.656.34901  AE  19-NOV-18   ECN-600141  01-JUN-18   TOOL.656.34901  AC
4022.666.82361  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600163  09-AUG-18   4022.666.82361  AA
4022.673.06791  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600163  09-AUG-18   4022.673.06791  AA
4022.673.06791  AD  18-JAN-19   ECN-600163  09-AUG-18   4022.673.06791  AA
4022.640.56121  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600181  06-JUL-18   4022.640.56121  AA
4022.666.82361  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600192  18-OCT-18   4022.666.82361  AB
4022.673.06791  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600192  18-OCT-18   4022.673.06791  AB
4022.673.06791  AD  18-JAN-19   ECN-600192  18-OCT-18   4022.673.06791  AB
TOOL.656.30131  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600200  08-AUG-18   TOOL.656.30131  AB
TOOL.656.34901  AE  19-NOV-18   ECN-600200  08-AUG-18   TOOL.656.34901  AD
ANCI.630.87322  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600205  06-JUL-18   ANCI.630.87322  AA
4022.667.18762  AC  13-SEP-18   ECN-600207  06-JUL-18   4022.667.18762  AB
4022.651.66291  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600222  12-SEP-18   4022.651.66291  AA
ANCI.481.82264  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600227  24-OCT-18   ANCI.481.82264  AA
ANCI.630.61341  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600227  24-OCT-18   ANCI.630.61341  AA
TOOL.630.61341  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600227  24-OCT-18   TOOL.630.61341  AA
4022.666.94631  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600229  14-NOV-18   4022.666.94631  AA
4022.666.94641  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600229  14-NOV-18   4022.666.94641  AA
4022.666.94651  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600229  14-NOV-18   4022.666.94651  AA
4022.666.94661  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600229  14-NOV-18   4022.666.94661  AA
4022.666.94671  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600229  14-NOV-18   4022.666.94671  AA
4022.666.94781  AD  04-DEC-18   ECN-600229  14-NOV-18   4022.666.94781  AC
4022.670.99451  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600230  14-NOV-18   4022.670.99451  AA
4022.655.46092  AZ  19-FEB-19   ECN-600232  14-NOV-18   4022.655.46092  AX
4022.655.46092  BA  20-FEB-19   ECN-600232  14-NOV-18   4022.655.46092  AX
4022.670.96101  AB  04-DEC-18   ECN-600255  13-AUG-18   4022.670.96101  AA
4022.670.99631  AB  04-DEC-18   ECN-600255  13-AUG-18   4022.670.99631  AA
4022.451.83711  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600273  21-JUL-18   4022.451.83711  AA
4022.480.42711  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600280  21-JUL-18   4022.480.42711  AB
ANCI.477.04323  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600302  23-JUL-18   ANCI.477.04323  AA
4022.471.80311  AB  03-SEP-18   ECN-600330  23-JUL-18   4022.471.80311  AA
ANCI.477.55803  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600342  24-JUL-18   ANCI.477.55803  AB
4022.631.25933  AC  20-NOV-18   ECN-600382  31-JUL-18   4022.631.25933  AB
4022.631.45942  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600382  31-JUL-18   4022.631.45942  AB
4022.631.25915  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600384  31-JUL-18   4022.631.25915  AB
4022.631.25953  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600384  31-JUL-18   4022.631.25953  AB
4022.630.36425  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600385  31-JUL-18   4022.630.36425  AB
4022.631.25993  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600385  31-JUL-18   4022.631.25993  AB
4022.630.36392  AD  19-NOV-18   ECN-600386  31-JUL-18   4022.630.36392  AC
4022.631.45902  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600386  31-JUL-18   4022.631.45902  AB
4022.474.20881  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600387  31-JUL-18   4022.474.20881  AB
4022.631.25984  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600387  31-JUL-18   4022.631.25984  AB
4022.486.91775  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600388  31-JUL-18   4022.486.91775  AB
4022.631.25963  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600388  31-JUL-18   4022.631.25963  AB
4022.631.25946  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600389  31-JUL-18   4022.631.25946  AB
4022.658.41312  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600390  31-JUL-18   4022.658.41312  AA
4022.658.41332  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600390  31-JUL-18   4022.658.41332  AA
4022.630.36435  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600391  31-JUL-18   4022.630.36435  AB
ANCI.477.90553  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600394  31-JUL-18   ANCI.477.90553  AA
TOOL.653.53011  AC  06-DEC-18   ECN-600444  01-AUG-18   TOOL.653.53011  AB
4022.621.01043  AC  22-JAN-19   ECN-600446  01-AUG-18   4022.621.01043  AA
REQS.621.13580  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600483  02-AUG-18   REQS.621.13580  AB
4022.648.67662  AE  04-DEC-18   ECN-600497  11-OCT-18   4022.648.67662  AC
4022.472.11842  AE  19-NOV-18   ECN-600498  07-AUG-18   4022.472.11842  AD
4022.637.31472  AD  19-NOV-18   ECN-600498  07-AUG-18   4022.637.31472  AC
4022.637.31512  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600498  07-AUG-18   4022.637.31512  AB
4022.642.18582  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600498  07-AUG-18   4022.642.18582  AB
4022.645.05811  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600498  07-AUG-18   4022.645.05811  AB
4022.651.64552  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600498  07-AUG-18   4022.651.64552  AB
4022.665.33071  AD  19-NOV-18   ECN-600498  07-AUG-18   4022.665.33071  AC
4022.669.84412  AE  19-NOV-18   ECN-600498  07-AUG-18   4022.669.84412  AC
4022.670.88171  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600498  07-AUG-18   4022.670.88171  AB
4022.636.44553  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600499  07-AUG-18   4022.636.44553  AB
4022.636.67631  AD  20-NOV-18   ECN-600499  07-AUG-18   4022.636.67631  AC
4022.642.17912  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600499  07-AUG-18   4022.642.17912  AB
4022.472.90841  AD  19-NOV-18   ECN-600500  07-AUG-18   4022.472.90841  AC
4022.636.63621  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600500  07-AUG-18   4022.636.63621  AB
4022.666.57161  AF  19-NOV-18   ECN-600500  07-AUG-18   4022.666.57161  AD
4022.430.26651  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600501  07-AUG-18   4022.430.26651  AA
4022.666.57151  AF  19-NOV-18   ECN-600501  07-AUG-18   4022.666.57151  AD
4022.669.84422  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600501  07-AUG-18   4022.669.84422  AA
4022.669.84452  AE  19-NOV-18   ECN-600501  07-AUG-18   4022.669.84452  AC
4022.636.62542  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600502  07-AUG-18   4022.636.62542  AB
4022.637.31462  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600502  07-AUG-18   4022.637.31462  AB
4022.637.31532  AC  20-NOV-18   ECN-600502  07-AUG-18   4022.637.31532  AB
4022.640.26801  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600502  07-AUG-18   4022.640.26801  AB
4022.659.61921  AE  19-NOV-18   ECN-600502  07-AUG-18   4022.659.61921  AD
4022.482.96921  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600503  07-AUG-18   4022.482.96921  AB
4022.637.31542  AC  20-NOV-18   ECN-600503  07-AUG-18   4022.637.31542  AB
4022.651.64542  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600503  07-AUG-18   4022.651.64542  AB
4022.659.83002  AD  19-NOV-18   ECN-600503  07-AUG-18   4022.659.83002  AC
4022.666.57102  AE  19-NOV-18   ECN-600503  07-AUG-18   4022.666.57102  AC
4022.669.84432  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600503  07-AUG-18   4022.669.84432  AA
4022.636.67714  AD  19-NOV-18   ECN-600504  07-AUG-18   4022.636.67714  AC
4022.636.60362  AG  20-NOV-18   ECN-600505  07-AUG-18   4022.636.60362  AF
TOOL.451.13122  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600506  07-AUG-18   TOOL.451.13122  AA
TOOL.631.70563  AC  06-DEC-18   ECN-600531  08-AUG-18   TOOL.631.70563  AB
TOOL.638.68291  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600538  08-AUG-18   TOOL.638.68291  AA
TOOL.484.85333  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600545  08-AUG-18   TOOL.484.85333  AB
REQS.200.40010  AB  04-DEC-18   ECN-600551  08-AUG-18   REQS.200.40010  AA
TOOL.666.96951  AC  05-SEP-18   ECN-600555  08-AUG-18   TOOL.666.96951  AB
TOOL.651.66051  AE  05-SEP-18   ECN-600557  08-AUG-18   TOOL.651.66051  AD
TOOL.656.65155  AF  09-OCT-18   ECN-600557  08-AUG-18   TOOL.656.65155  AE
TOOL.481.55523  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600559  08-AUG-18   TOOL.481.55523  AB
TOOL.481.55513  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600560  13-AUG-18   TOOL.481.55513  AB
4022.471.98221  AF  19-NOV-18   ECN-600591  15-AUG-18   4022.471.98221  AE
TOOL.200.10472  AB  28-SEP-18   ECN-600591  15-AUG-18   TOOL.200.10472  AA
4022.664.60871  AF  28-SEP-18   ECN-600592  15-AUG-18   4022.664.60871  AE
TOOL.670.53661  AC  19-NOV-18   ECN-600594  15-AUG-18   TOOL.670.53661  AB
TOOL.651.66082  AC  05-SEP-18   ECN-600602  15-AUG-18   TOOL.651.66082  AB
4022.622.47631  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600603  23-AUG-18   4022.622.47631  AB
4022.648.67662  AE  04-DEC-18   ECN-600603  23-AUG-18   4022.648.67662  AA
4022.656.19881  AF  04-DEC-18   ECN-600603  23-AUG-18   4022.656.19881  AE
ANCI.631.42433  AB  19-NOV-18   ECN-600604  28-AUG-18   ANCI.631.42433  AA
4022.666.57102  AE  19-NOV-18   ECN-600627  07-SEP-18   4022.666.57102  AD
4022.666.57151  AF  19-NOV-18   ECN-600627  07-SEP-18   4022.666.57151  AE
4022.666.57161  AF  19-NOV-18   ECN-600627  07-SEP-18   4022.666.57161  AE
4022.672.08141  AF  10-DEC-18   ECN-600654  31-AUG-18   4022.672.08141  AD
4022.651.66291  AC  04-DEC-18   ECN-600722  02-OCT-18   4022.651.66291  AB
4022.669.84412  AE  19-NOV-18   ECN-600734  21-SEP-18   4022.669.84412  AD
4022.669.84452  AE  19-NOV-18   ECN-600734  21-SEP-18   4022.669.84452  AD
4022.668.04041  AB  04-DEC-18   ECN-600780  22-OCT-18   4022.668.04041  AA
4022.636.17781  AF  20-FEB-19   ECN-601136  20-DEC-18   4022.636.17781  AC
4022.632.53081  AJ  20-FEB-19   ECN-601137  20-DEC-18   4022.632.53081  AG
ANCI.620.02533  AB  18-JAN-19   ECN-601166  21-DEC-18   ANCI.620.02533  AA
ANCI.622.45562  AB  08-JAN-19   ECN-601166  21-DEC-18   ANCI.622.45562  AA
ANCI.482.57632  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601167  21-DEC-18   ANCI.482.57632  AB
ANCI.641.33262  AB  18-JAN-19   ECN-601167  21-DEC-18   ANCI.641.33262  AA
ANCI.647.50132  AB  08-JAN-19   ECN-601167  21-DEC-18   ANCI.647.50132  AA
REQS.668.68860  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601167  21-DEC-18   REQS.668.68860  AB
TOOL.666.79811  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601167  21-DEC-18   TOOL.666.79811  AA
ANCI.487.22523  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601168  21-DEC-18   ANCI.487.22523  AB
ANCI.623.18371  AB  08-JAN-19   ECN-601168  21-DEC-18   ANCI.623.18371  AA
ANCI.668.79151  AD  08-JAN-19   ECN-601168  21-DEC-18   ANCI.668.79151  AC
ANCI.670.25401  AD  08-JAN-19   ECN-601168  21-DEC-18   ANCI.670.25401  AC
TOOL.453.35882  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601168  21-DEC-18   TOOL.453.35882  AB
TOOL.620.92001  AB  08-JAN-19   ECN-601168  21-DEC-18   TOOL.620.92001  AA
TOOL.639.88972  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601168  21-DEC-18   TOOL.639.88972  AB
ANCI.620.00881  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601169  21-DEC-18   ANCI.620.00881  AB
ANCI.622.45972  AB  08-JAN-19   ECN-601169  21-DEC-18   ANCI.622.45972  AA
ANCI.631.21601  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601169  21-DEC-18   ANCI.631.21601  AB
ANCI.632.41993  AB  08-JAN-19   ECN-601169  21-DEC-18   ANCI.632.41993  AA
ANCI.646.89201  AB  08-JAN-19   ECN-601169  21-DEC-18   ANCI.646.89201  AA
TOOL.620.01202  AD  18-JAN-19   ECN-601169  21-DEC-18   TOOL.620.01202  AC
TOOL.669.14161  AB  08-JAN-19   ECN-601169  21-DEC-18   TOOL.669.14161  AA
TOOL.435.61514  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601170  21-DEC-18   TOOL.435.61514  AB
TOOL.455.11101  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601170  21-DEC-18   TOOL.455.11101  AB
TOOL.621.42921  AC  08-JAN-19   ECN-601170  21-DEC-18   TOOL.621.42921  AB
TOOL.621.42931  AB  08-JAN-19   ECN-601170  21-DEC-18   TOOL.621.42931  AA
REQS.630.51780  AB  07-JAN-19   ECN-601217  21-DEC-18   REQS.630.51780  AA
4022.632.53081  AJ  20-FEB-19   ECN-601523  20-FEB-19   4022.632.53081  AH
4022.636.17781  AF  20-FEB-19   ECN-601523  20-FEB-19   4022.636.17781  AD
4022.655.46092  BA  20-FEB-19   ECN-601523  20-FEB-19   4022.655.46092  AZ
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit of output data?  It can be masked so that you're not posting actual data.  Usually having duplicate ID values indicates an improper join or WHERE clause.  You might also check out the `ROW_NUMBER()` method in T-SQL.

Comment: @MarkMoretto I updated the results as you have requested.

Comment: @MarkMoretto: `row_number()` is not specific to "T-SQL" - it's part of the SQL standard and Oracle supported it decades before Microsoft

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! I didn't even realize that.  Now, if only Access SQL would keep up with the times...

Comment: @PavanDittakavi Your query looks pretty good, but it seems reversed.  What is the ECN ID? Is there one for the first Item ID? Tentatively, without eliminating or reworking the ECN-ID field, you won't get a unique ItemID/ItemRevisionID composite result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `distinct` keyword after `select` or `group by` for every column in `select`

Comment: I do not want a unique column1 or unique column2. I want unique combinations of column1 and column2.

Comment: @PavanDittakavi: `distinct` applies to all columns in the select list, not just one